# Tool to generate worst-case data for a given SQL query

Tags: sql, database, performance, testing, optimization

I would like to populate some tables with a large amount of data in order to empirically test the performance of an SQL query in the worst case scenario (well, as close to it as possible).

I considered using random values. But this would require manual adjustment to get even close to the worst case. Unconstrained random values are no good for a worst case because they tend mostly to be unique -- in which case an index on a single column should perform about as well as a compound index. On the other hand, random values chosen from too small a set will result in a large fraction of the rows being returned, which is uninteresting because it reflects not so much *search* performance as *listing* performance.

I also considered just looking at EXPLAIN PLAN, but this is not empirical, and also the explanation varies, partly depending on the data that you already have, rather than the worst case.

**Is there a tool that analyzes a given SQL query (and the db schema and ideally indexes), then generates a large data set (of a given size) that will cause the query to perform as close to worst-case as possible?**

Any RDBMS is fine.

I would also be interested in alternative approaches for gaining this level of insight into worst-case behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**:  There is no worst case scenario because every case can be made much worse, usually just by adding more data with the same distribution.

**Long answer**:

I would recommend to you to look not for the worst case scenario, but for an "overblown realistic scenario" in which you start from production data, define what you consider a large amount of entities (for each table separately), multiply by a factor of two or three, and generate the data from the production data you have by hand.

For example, if your production data has 1000 car models from 150 car manufacturers and you will decide you might need 10000 models from 300 manufacturers, you will first double the number of records in the referenced table (manufacturers), then generate a "copy" of existing 1000 car models to create another 1000 cars referencing those generated manufacturers, and then generating 4 more cars per each existing one, every time copying the existing distribution of values based on case by case decisions.  This means new unique values in some columns, and simply copied values in others.

Do not forget to regenerate statistics after you are done.  Why exactly am I saying this?  Because you want to test the *best* possible query plan given the query, data, and schema, and optimize *that*.

Rationale: Queries are not algorithms.  The query optimizer chooses a suitable query plan not only based on the query, but also on information about how big the tables approximately are, index coverage, operator selectivity, and so on.  You are not really interested in learning how poorly chosen plans, or plans for unrealistically populated database execute.  This could even induce you to add ill chosen indexes, and ill chosen indexes can make production performance worse.  You want to learn and test what happens with the *best* plan for a realistic albeit large numbers of rows.

While you could test with 1,000,000 car models, odds are that such production content is science fiction for your specific database schema and queries.  However, it would be even less useful to test with the number of car models equaling the number of car manufacturers in your database.  While such a distribution might happen to be the *worst* possible one for your application, you will learn almost nothing from basing your metrics on it.

Comment: Although I neglected to say it at the start, at the end of my question I mentioned that I'd like to see (as close as possible to) the worst case **for a given size** -- there, a worst case is possible since there are only finitely many cases.

Comment: Also, I may not know in advance what kind of data my customers may enter into my system -- although I see where you're coming from with the car example, my situation is more complex and it is not so easy to predict what will happen. I'd like my app to respond reasonably, no matter what surprises the customers may throw at me :-)

Comment: Your point about indexes is an excellent one, and optimizing for worst-case situations can hurt the non-worst-case situations! But I think in some situations, there is an argument to be made for such a trade-off -- suppose you genuinely expect to have millions of rows and you don't know what your customers will throw at you?

Comment: @antinome - my answer is based on testing methodology we use with a database consisting of about 300 tables and 5000 columns, none of which have any relation to cars.  Yes we do not always predict well what will happen (surprises include both sizes and value distributions), but that is where maintenance steps in.  If a customer can make the product slow in ways that we failed to test against, the experience should be used to modify the test data generator.  Always learn from projected production data, rather than from "the worst data that could theoretically fit the schema".

Comment: @antinome - I agree that it is useful to try looking beyond the corner as well, and trade-offs between scenarios are inevitable.  However, the bigger the database is expected to be, the more specific analysis (assumptions) one needs to accept, attempting to predict at least roughly how the basic dimensions of the data will be distributed.  This is then used to set assumptions about granularity, update throughput, disaster recovery, response times... basically everything.

Comment: your approach probably gives you better results than if you optimized for the worst case -- but at the same time, doesn't it take more work to go back and make changes later than if you  the worst case up front? You said not to optimize for the worst case, but supposing it saves maintenance later, why not? (in any case, +1 for a thoughtful answer and some good points)

Comment: @antinome - I'll try to do anything that saves maintenance later, of course.  However, the worst case is usually a function of thousands of parameters, and the space of possible inputs is quite fuzzy.

Comment: I basically agree with your approach -- but I do find the idea of "I know it can run in X milliseconds with Y millions of rows, no matter what the data" to be very attractive. You have pointed out some disadvantages but they are ones I could accept in some situations. Of course, maybe it is too difficult to build such a tool, maybe my idea is a pipe dream.

Comment: In thinking about your points more, perhaps I have been naive -- I'll accept your answer in a couple of days.